# Facebook Javascript SDK Login - POST Response to PHP

Tags: php, facebook-javascript-sdk

The code below is Facebook's "Login for the Web with the JavaScript SDK", which will send the browser's email address and name to the client-side javascript.
But how do I get the email and name POSted to a PHP file on my website server, so I can log the user in using PHP?

```
function statusChangeCallback(response) {
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
        testAPI();
    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
        document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' + 'into this app.';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' + 'into Facebook.';
    }
}
function checkLoginState() {
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response){
        statusChangeCallback(response);
    });
}
function testAPI() {
        FB.api('/me',  {fields: 'email,name'},function(response) {
            document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Thanks for logging in again, ' + JSON.stringify(response) + '!<br/><img src="https://graph.facebook.com/'+response.id+'/picture?width=300" />';
    });
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: true });
    $.getScript('//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js', function(){
        FB.init({
            appId: '211867502496511',
            cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
            xfbml: true, // parse social plugins on this page
            version: 'v2.5' // or v2.0, v2.1, v2.2, v2.3
        }); 
        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
            statusChangeCallback(response);
        });
    });
});
function doalog(){
    FB.login(function(response){
        statusChangeCallback(response);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the workhorse of manual networking in client side JavaScript: the [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest).

Basically this is an object that allows you to manually communicate with your server. You can use it in conjunction with a [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) object to POST the data do your server. The request you send can be handled like any other form POST request.

Once you have the email and name you can do this.

```
var name = theMethodYouUseToGetTheName();
var email = theMethodYouUseToGetTheEmail();

var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.onReadyStateChanged = function() {
    if (request.readyState == 4) {
        if (request.status == 200) {
            // your request has been sent and you might have a response
        } else {
           // there has been an error
        }
    }
}

var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("name", name);
formData.append("email", email);

request.open("POST", "http://yourwebsite.com/your/php/file.php", true);
request.send(formData);
```

Then on your server you can access the POST data like normal using

```
$userName = $_POST["name"];
$userEmail = $_POST["email"];
```

Comment: Yes, but that would allow a hacker to log in under any name he wanted by hijacking the javascript. He could log in under his own name but then forward the javascript under another

Comment: @user2790911 If I'm not mistaken the Facebook API provides more information than just name and email, including a unique ID. No matter what you do on your web page **you are going to have an endpoint that accepts these requests** so if a hacker really wanted to he could just send a request from his own program. I recommend you read the [Facebook API Best Practices section](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/best-practices). Using an XMLHttpRequest does not violate them.

Comment: If the authentication is from Facebook to the website server via the client then the client can intercept the message and change it. If Facebook send the message directly to the server saying they have checked the authenticity of user@gmail.com and it's safe to log him in then the hacker can't intercept the message.